# How to get all current category products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category

I want to get all the products available on the current category page I tried this code

```
 public function getProduct()
{
        $check = $this->_registry->registry('current_category')->getProductCollection();
        return $check->getAllIds();
```

now this code is working good for non-configurable products but in cofigurable products it show a null Array.
I just want to get all the Products on the current categories. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCategory()
{
    $check = $this->_registry->registry('current_category')->getProductCollection();
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load(    $check);
    return $category;
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
     return $this->getCategory()->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
}
```

It's working.